# What is Deadline of Manage Firebase installations implementation ? What is impact of deprecated Firebase installation ID in Mobile app?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

What is the Deadline for Manage Firebase installations implementation? What is the impact of deprecated Firebase installation ID in the Mobile app?

We have an existing project using Firebase installation ID as it is deprecated now. If we will not remove it from the mobile app how it will impact the notification? what is the last date to implement a Manage Firebase installations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [Cloud Messaging version 22.0.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#messaging_v22-0-0) published on **May 11, 2021** - they have removed this dependency from their SDK.

> Removed dependency on the deprecated Firebase Instance ID SDK.
>
> Caution: This is a breaking change for apps that use FCM and the deprecated Firebase Instance ID API to manage registration tokens.
> We strongly recommend [migrating to FCM's token APIs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/manage-installations#fid-iid). **If you're unable to migrate to the replacement APIs, add a direct dependency on the firebase-iid library to your build.gradle file.**

You can still keep working with `firebase-iid` directly for now. This is there so we have enough time to migrate to new apis. You should consider migrating to new apis according to your schedule.

---

**Is there any official deadline to implement new Manage Firebase installations?**

> No direction on this by Firebase team yet.

**What is the impact on IOS and Android App if we keep using firebase-iid?**

> It will keep working as it does today. However since it is not being maintained, it will not receive any new feature updates as the counterpart would.

**What will happen if user will have latest os and that does not support the firebase-iid?**

> You package your `firebase-iid` code with your app bundle/apk. You do not rely on OS having it. So it seems a long way to go before your code stops working at all.

Comment: Is there any official deadline to implement new Manage Firebase installations? What is the impact on IOS and Android App if we keep using firebase-iid?  What will happen if user will have latest os in device and that does not support the firebase-iid?

Comment: See the UPDATED answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have asked this question to Firebase's official community also waiting for their answer to be double sure.

Comment: If we will replace the IID API with FCM's token APIs. It will use the same IID token from the device or create a new one? How it will impact the IID stored on the SFCloud messaging server?
What is the right way to implement in ios and android without any reinstallation from the user device?

Comment: Old tokens will still keep working the way they used to. Whenever a new token value is received, your app is supposed to send this new token to your server anyway, so it should be handled just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer few more question : 
What is the impact of replacing the deprecated FIID API with Firebase installations Apis on Mobile ios/android app and on messaging server?

1) Will it use the same IID token from the existing device or create a new token?
2) What will be the impact on the SFCloud messaging server or any other server that manages the token ID of each user device? Will it have both old (by IID) and new (Firebase installations) Token id from 1 device? 3)What is the right way to implement in ios and android without any reinstallation/login from the user device?

Comment: All of these should be asked in a separate question for clarity & discoverability.